# Como habilitar a câmera do macBook no Simulador?

Tags: xcode

Estou fazendo um APP no xCode que utiliza a câmera para fazer vídeos porém não consigo usar a câmera pelo Simulador.

Existe alguma forma para habilitar a câmera para o Simulador?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infelizmente não é possível acessar a câmera do MacBook no Simulator. Recursos como a câmera podem ser testados apenas em um aparelho real.

Uma lista completa dos recursos que não podem ser testados no Simulator pode ser vista [aqui](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html)